# Count on Total Columns and Row Specific Table Wise Using Jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<body>
    <div id="collapseFour" class="accordion-body collapse">
        <div class="accordion-inner">          
            <div class="datagrid divscrollable ">      
                <span>Input Page Design</span>           
                <table id="tblClaimedbyOthers">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="iconth" width="300px">
                                <button id="btn" type="button" class="btnmergecell imgClass2" style="float: left">Click Here</button>                               
                                <span class="col-center">User</span>
                            </th>                           
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="newscrollClaim ">
                                    <table class="datagrid" id="tbluser">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>
                                                    Column A
                                                </th>
                                                <th>
                                                    Column B
                                                </th>
                                                <th>
                                                    Column C
                                                </th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr id="1">
                                                <td valign="top">
                                                    <div class="dsbColBgColor">
                                                        <span class="label">David </span>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="dsbColBgColor">
                                                        <span class="label">Daniel </span>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="dsbColBgColor">
                                                        <span class="label">Robin </span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td valign="top">
                                                    <div class="dsbColBgColor">
                                                        <span class="label">David</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="dsbColBgColor">
                                                        <span class="label">Rose</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td valign="top">
                                                    <div class="dsbColBgColor">
                                                        <span class="label">Daniel </span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </td>                          
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>   
                <span>Output Page Design</span>           
                <table id="tblClaimedbyOthers">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="iconth" width="300px">                                                         
                                <span class="col-center">User</span>
                            </th>                            
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="newscrollClaim ">
                                    <table class="datagrid">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>
                                                    3[6]
                                                </th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>                                        
                                    </table>                                 
                                </div>
                            </td>                           
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

In this HTML page I want to click event on button id (btn)  and there is output.
I want to need it below mention here

In this html page I want to count all column and row count in specific table id (tbluser) there is three column A,B,C and

- Column A mention 3 Row
- Column B mention 2 Row
- Column C mention 1 Row

And I want to count total Column and Row in 3[6] 
How is Work this in jquery ?

http://jsfiddle.net/AP2014/q5j9k/1/

Comment: Where is your current jQuery code?

Comment: your provided markup is all messy.. please clean this up and hit "update" : http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/q5j9k/